# ScrollIntoView to scroll between divs not working

Tags: reactjs

I have a horizontal container of 10 divs and I want to scroll between divs. Eg. When clicking div3 and if I am in div1 position, it scrolls horizontally to div5 to show the user div5.

I have a scrollIntoView happening within `useEffect` but at the moment it scrolls whenever it wants and sometimes it doesn't.

This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (divId) {
        if (divId === 3) {
            divs.current.childNodes[5].scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'center',
                inline: 'center',
            });
        }
    }
}, [currentYear]);
```

any idea whats wrong with my code and if not, how else can I have an horizontal scroll in React hooks?

Thanks!

note: I have checked and `divId` state shows true whenever I click the div i want so the state isn't the issue.

Comment: Why not just `&&` your two conditionals into one `if()`? And, if you `console.log()` out the value of `divs.current.childNodes[5]`, is it the expected DOM element?

Comment: it does show the expected DOM element, but again still only happens once. When I am back to divId === 3, so scroll again horizontally to the div I clicked in order to get to the DOM element and click to scrollIntoView it just doesn't do anything.